# Is it possible to proxy producers' capital with corporate bond in a macro model?

Tags: macroeconomics, financial-economics, new-keynesian-economics

I'm trying to reproduce Gertler-Karádi (2013) model. How far-fetched is the thought to use the amount of corporate bond as an input of production?
[image]
Thank you in advance.

Comment: I think this is what Piketty does, if this is of any help. ("Corporations are included in private wealth through the market value of equities.", in the Appendix of http://piketty.pse.ens.fr/files/PikettyZucman2013WP.pdf )

Comment: To make sure I understand you: you're asking whether or not it makes sense to add corporate bond holdings into the production function? As in, bond holdings can somehow be converted into a meaningful production input? Seems reasonable. However, I might consider lagged holdings as input for current period production, to offset the fact that bonds are less liquid that, for example, cash holdings.

Comment: Thanks Ululo and 123 for the helpful comments! (Yes @123, this is exactly what I'm asking.)

Comment: Happy to help. And I apologize for all of the typos!